# SQL08 ConnectionString: Data Source= vs Server=

Tags: sql-server-2008

For an asp.net webapp, is there a functional difference between a connection string (in Web.config) that uses:

Data Source=[WIN-MachineName]\SQLEXPRESS

vs

Server=[WIN-MachineName]\SQLEXPRESS

Since both refer to the instance of SQLServer one wants to think they'd be interchangeable.